# Start Tmux with specific applications on each pane?

Tags: linux, fedora, configuration, tmux, session

I want to start tmux on startup with four panes (two horizontal, two vertical) and `cmus`, `ranger` in two, and `vim` and `urxvt` terminal in the other two.

I tried to configure `~/.tmux.conf` myself but couldn't achieve what I wanted properly.

I'm not very familiar with the concept of session, and they *die* whenever I turn off my computer.

It would be perfect if I could permanently save a session with specific applications opened on each pane of it, and refer to it when needed.

Comment: Unless the tmux session is running on a remote host, of course they will die when you turn off your machine; how would you expect them to persist without any power?

Comment: @jasonwryan saving themselves in a file, and reloading the setting (panes, applications) when I restore? I meant that they're not restorable. I am very okay with programming tmux without the use of sessions as well, as it's not the topic here, but a suggestion that came to my mind.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened/5753059?s=6|5.7680#5753059

Comment: Thanks, but that link is mainly about windows and naming them, though I think tmuxinator might help with specifying the programs to be run on panes. I'll research on it, but still looking for native or pluginless way to achieve the desired in tmux.

Comment: That SO answer is *exactly* what you have asked for; the second window *is* split into panes (`splitw`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using tmux-plugins called tmux-resurrect
for more info : https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect